# How to: sudo -u <username> in sudoer?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, visudo

I need to launch a command with sudo rights out of a php file (user: www-data), explicitly as user `www-data`:

```
<?php
    $command = 'sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/script.py';
    shell_exec($command);
?>
```

to be able to use sudo for `www-data` I want to put the command in sudoers (`sudo visudo`), like:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/script.py
```

or

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: -u www-data /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/script.py
```

but the syntax is wrong (error message from visudo).
The following is working with sudoers (correct syntax)

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/script.py
```

but doesn't work for my script (apache error in log file):

```
Sorry, user www-data is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/script.py' as www-data on raspberrypi.
```

it seems it needs `sudo -u www-data`. How can I solve this?

Comment: its not python you need sudo for, it would be the script. so make the script executable then owned by www-data then it would be `www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/script.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to use `sudo` to allow `www-data` to run commands as `www-data`, but you can easily do so:

```
www-data ALL=(www-data) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/script.py
```

The problem with your approaches was that you tried to add the command `sudo -u www-data ..` to sudoers, which corresponds to double-sudo `sudo sudo -u www-data ..`

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now it makes sense and it works perfectly. visudo = www-data ALL=(www-data) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/script.py AND shell_exec() with 'sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/script.py' combined with the tipps from @Lawrence Cherone chown www-data script.py and chmod +x script.py.